# Can download progresses be sorted by time remaining in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

If this is not natively-available, are their any add-ons that would show you downloads in descending/ascending order based on time left?

Do other browsers allow such displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) can do the job. And its a pretty neat download manager.

[image]